# What are the pros and cons of specifying an include prefix in the source file versus in the search path parameter of the compiler?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

When a C or C++ library comes with several headers, they are usually in a specific folder. For example, OpenCV provides `cv.h` and `highgui.h` in a `opencv` folder.

The most common way to include them is to add this `opencv` folder to the search path of the pre-compiler (e.g. `gcc -I/pathto/opencv`), and simply include the headers by their filename in the source file (e.g. `#include <cv.h>`)

There is an alternative, as it is quite frequent that folders containing headers are with others (e.g. in `/usr/include` or some path common to the development team) in a parent folder. In this case, it is enough to specify the header folder in the source file (e.g. `#include <opencv/cv.h>`), if the parent folder is already in the path.

The only problem I can think of with this alternative is the case of a system where all the headers are in a single folder. However, this alternative prevents ambiguities (e.g. if two libraries have a `vector.h` header), makes it easier to set up another build system, and is probably more efficient regard to the search of the header file by the pre-compiler.

Given this analysis, I would tend toward the alternative, but a vast majority of code I found on internet use the first. For example, Google returns around 218000 results for `"#include <cv.h>"`, versus 79100 for `"#include <opencv/cv.h>"`. Am I missing advantages of the common way, or disadvantages of the alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have slightly different purposes, and I think need to be used carefully.

Consider the fact that in the `-I` case it was `/pathto/opencv`. You're suggesting possibly `#include <opencv/cv.h>` but you'd never write `#include </pathto/opencv/cv.h>`. There's a reason for that, which is that you expect `cv.h` is *always* in a directory called `opencv`, because that's how it's always released, whereas `pathto` is just where that library's files happen to have been installed on your machine (or on your distribution, whatever).

Anything that could conceivably differ depending where your code is being compiled, should be in the include path, so that it can be configured without modifying your source. Anything that is guaranteed to be the same wherever that particular `cv.h` is used can appear in the source, but it doesn't have to, so we need to decide whether we want it there.

As you've already noticed, it's useful to have it there as a disambiguator, especially for a file with a two-character name, but if you think that someone might want to put `cv.h` in a different place, then you should leave it out. That's pretty much the trade-off you're making - the header should always be in an `opencv` directory, but is it worth it to you to rely on that as a guarantee, as the price of disambiguating?

Comment: Thanks for giving these "rules" that generalize the also interesting points given in the other answers!

Answer (score 5):

My personal preference is to have `<opencv/cv.h>`.

Why ? Because I am human, with a limited brain, and much more important things to do than remember that `cv.h` comes from the `opencv` library.

Therefore, even though the libraries I work with are always in dedicated folders, I structure them as:

```
<specific library folder>/include/<library name>/...
```

This helps me remember where those headers come from.

I have known people saying it was useless, and that IDEs would bring you straight to the file anyway... but

- I don't always use an IDE
- I don't always want to *open* each include file merely to know which libraries this particular file is tied to

It also makes it much easier to organize the include list (and group related includes together).

Comment: So if I get it right, you actually specify the subfolder in both the source file and the compiler search path? That sounds like a good way to avoid ambiguities for both the compiler and human.

Comment: @user981733: in the search path, I only say `<specific library folder>/include` no matter how many subfolders there are in `include`.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess the main problem with using `#include <opencv/cv.h>` is that you don't necessarily want to add an entire parent path.

Taking an example where it has been installed to `/usr/local` when using the option with the full path, you'll need to add `-I/usr/local/include` to your command line.  That could have all kinds of side effects.

E.g. for a completely different application, someone may have installed GNU iconv libraries there.  Then suddenly, your application, which is also doing `#include <iconv.h>` is grabbing the headers from the standalone iconv library, instead of the implementation in glibc.

Obviously these are problems that do crop up from time to time, but by including more specific directories, you can hopefully minimise them.

Comment: That's sort of what `-i` and to a lesser extent `-I-` are for, but it's a pain to get right so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for the first version:

- you are not always able to install the headers/library in a standard path. Some time you do not have root access.
- you do not want to pollute the path adding all the path for all the libraries you have installed.
- for example you can have 2 version of the same library installed (in your case openCV) and you want some of your projects to be compiled with one library and some other with the other library. If you put them in the path then you get a name clash. For me this is one of the main reason (exactly for OpenCv I have version 1.x and 2.x installed and some projects compiled with 1.x and some with 2.x).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The third reason is a good point. About the first reason, isn't it still easier to install additional headers in your personal folder at the same location?

Comment: And I did not get if you second reason supports the common way or the alternative, as I would think that path pollution happens when too many folders are specified to the precompiler.

Comment: yes, my second reason is for when you install in different folders. If you install everything in the same folder then it could be Ok but you will run in a different problem: imagine you want to use two libraries from 2 other developers and each of them have the Constants.h?

Comment: Let's say you have both OpenCV1 and OpenCV2 such as (~/libs/opencv1/opencv/*.h and ~/libs/opencv2/opencv/*.h).  You can `-I~/libs/` if you want and `#include <opencv/cv.h>` will fail.  you then `-I~/libs/ -I~/libs/opencv2` (if you want v2) and it will give you the one you want while still retaining all the disambiguation.